# Android - AccountManager Twitter OAuth, no authentication challenges found

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter4j, accountmanager

I am trying to get OAuth token from AccountManager for twitter account and using it to follow a twitter handle using **Twitter4j**. But I am getting **no authenticating challenges found** TwitterException.

Bellow is the code to get the token and follow the user:

```
 try{

     AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(getActivity());
     Account twitterAccount = accountManager.getAccountsByType(AccountType.TWITTER.getType())[0];
 AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> tokenFuture =  accountManager.getAuthToken(twitterAccount, "com.twitter.android.oauth.token", null, true, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
                        Bundle bundle;
                        try {
                            bundle = result.getResult();
                            Intent intent = (Intent) bundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                            if (intent != null) {
                                // User input required
                                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                String token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                                Log.i(TAG, "Token:" + token);
                              userToken = token;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting token", e);
                        }

                }

            }, null);

            AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> secretFuture =   accountManager.getAuthToken(twitterAccount, "com.twitter.android.oauth.token.secret", null, true, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
                    Bundle bundle;
                    try {
                        bundle = result.getResult();
                        Intent intent = (Intent) bundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                        if (intent != null) {
                            // User input required
                            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            String secret = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Secret Token:" + secret);
                           userSecret = secret;

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error getting token", e);
                    }

                }

            }, null);
            ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configurationBuilder
                    .setOAuthConsumerKey(<Consumer-key>);
            configurationBuilder
                    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(<Consumer-Secret>);

              configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(userToken);
            configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(userSecret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configurationBuilder.build()).getInstance();
            User user = twitter.createFriendship(param.getUserName());
            Toast.makeText(followListActivity,"Followed user @"+user.getScreenName()+" :)",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


        }  catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Getting this exception:

```
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[ec1fe56d-1e3b4ac5 3ea58453-a92e09a2], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.2}
at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:178)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:71)
at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.fillInIDAndScreenName(TwitterBaseImpl.java:128)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.verifyCredentials(TwitterImpl.java:545)
at asynctask.FollowTwitterUserAsyncTask.doInBackground(FollowTwitterUserAsyncTask.java:113)
 at asynctask.FollowTwitterUserAsyncTask.doInBackground(FollowTwitterUserAsyncTask.java:33)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentials(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:438)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:418)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:367)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:301)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
at twitter4j.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:35)
at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:142)
```

Please point out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Down voter, can you give a reason? Please point out why. Any help appreciated, am kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t do anything wrong at all, that’s an issue with the library. In Android, a HTTP response code of 401 causes an IOException be thrown. The library implementor [checks for the message string of the IOException to catch it](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/74546820dd2e99012b9be4b636e995bee127d177/twitter4j-core/src/internal-http/java/twitter4j/HttpResponseImpl.java#L35-44), however your message string is slightly different so the exception handling doesn’t execute. Unluckily, the issue tracker is not enabled for [that GitHub project](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j), but you may try to contact [the project owner](https://github.com/yusuke), maybe he will fix it for you. Otherwise you will have to modify the library code and build it yourself.

Comment: And, how do you think that exception should be handled?

Comment: Even if we handle it, its a 401, thats a fail.

Comment: As the code says (see first link) the reason is a token expired and the solution should be to call the same request a second time, but the library doesn’t do it since the error message is different in your android version. It seems the library needs fixing. If the project owner is not responding, you can fork the github project to do that. I believe comparing the message string isn’t a good approach. Perhaps its just sufficicent to do the call a second time in every case. If there is a different cause of the Exception, it is likely to happen again.